# Microsoft sync framework DateTime problem

Tags: c#, wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a problem with synchronizing DateTime data. When DateTime data is synced it always uses the servers local timezone. I have been searching and reading about this and only found this official workaround:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842545

This workaround was posted back in 2007. Is it really true that Microsoft hasn't released a fix for this problem? If not, is this workaround the only way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over both the client and the server, it is always preferable to work with UTC DateTimes (timezone independant). You should then always persist to database (or file or whatever persisting you use) DateTimes with DateTimeKind UTC:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx

The you can delegate to the client to correctly show the time (given the users timezone).

If you haven't got control over both client and server, I see no workaround but the workaround given by Microsoft. The point is that UTC times should always be used when potentially facing clients in  different time zones.

Regards, 
Torgeir

Comment: Using UTC does not overcome this problem. System.Data.DataSet ignores the DateTimeKind when deserializing, and adjust the time according the difference between the client and server timezones.